# How to generate a guilloche effect at the edge of certificate of authenticity or such?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, software-recommendation

I need to generate a guilloche border for certificate of authenticity (CoA) to be at the edge of the CoA. I'm talking here about the infinite curve that makes the certificate look "legit".

I'm planning on creating such a curve with a plotter with ball pen in it. That would ensure the curve is always a little bit unique (CoA will be scanned so that I can later approve it's a authentic certificate and misperfections in ball pen line will serve as a great generator of entropy, making it almost impossible to tamper with).

How to make such a curve? Possibly in Illustrator, but I don't really care which way.

EDIT2: Found out Illustrator has 'Scribble' filter. This is what I've done with it and kinda what I want to achieve, but in a more 'sophisticated' manner... [image: sample]

Comment: errr... [Excentro?](http://www.excourse.com/excentro/)

Comment: The curve can not be infinite  or your plotter would take infinite time to plot it. Howabout just using a watermarked paper. Besides its not the certificate paper that holds the secret ist the fact that it is being backed up by a phonecall to the original author.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for exactly what Scott posted. Not sure if it is THE thing I need but at least we know how it's called.

Comment: @joojaa infinite as in letter "∞" is "infinite"

Comment: @Scott It is exactly what I'm talking about. Didn't know it's called Guilloché. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: the shape is pretty easy to do on your own too, but its better to script as it gives you faster feedbacktime.

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator does not really excel at this sort of operation. This is why I linked to [Excentro](http://www.excourse.com/excentro/) in the comment above. Excentro is specifically designed to create guillochés and it's artwork is exportable (as vector) to Illustrator. Of course, I realize Excentro is an extra cost.

The ways I can think to try and pull it off with only Illustrator include:

- Pattern brushes
- Transform Effects

With a **Pattern Brush**, you simply create tile-able base artwork:

[image]

Drag that to the **Brushes Panel** and choose `Pattern Brush` for the first pop-up window.

The second window will allow you to set some auto-generated corners (Illustrator CC or newer only):

[image]

You can try a few of the auto-corner options while the dialog is open to see if any fit well. If not, you may need to generate a custom corner. Unfortunately, custom corner creation is much more intricate and dependent upon the actual artwork. So, I won't go into custom pattern brush corner creation here, but there are tutorials on the web.

After clicking `OK` in the brush dialog you can simply draw a shape and apply the brush to it.

[image]

The more intricate and detailed the original brush artwork is the more extensive the overall final appearance can be.

**Effects** which create smooth curves really come down to `Stylize > Scribble` and `Distort & Transform > Zig Zag`. Neither of these on their own does, what I would consider a good job:

[image]

Zig-Zag would require rounded corners to work if no manual alteration is desired. But ultimately it's just one path and not what I would consider a guilloché. You'd have to double-up objects and carefully configure things to get any sort of guilloché aspect.

Lastly you could *combine* an effect with a pattern brush:

So I start with simple base art and apply an effect to create a guilloché-like circle:

[image]

I then apply another effect (saying `OK` to the warning that pops up) to move and copy this object horizontally.

[image]

Then I draw a rectangle with **no fill** and **no stroke** and move it **behind** all other artwork. The rectangle "splits" the first and last circle in half. This ensures repeating brush patterns will repeat at that "half circle" or "half emblem", thus lining up the area of repeat.

[image]

I then drag that artwork to the **Brush Panel** and choose **Pattern Brush** when asked. I set the auto-corner option to `Auto-Slice` and click `OK`.

Then simply draw a rectangle and click the brush I just created:

[image]
<sub>My pattern-defining rectangle is slightly off on one end. This is resulting in a small overlap where the repeat happens. Easily corrected, but I closed the file (without saving it) before I noticed the repeat issue.</sub>

Is this *technically* a intertwining guilloché? No, but it does *look* like it. Depending upon your original base art, you can create some very nice, intricate, appearing brushes in this way.

Answer (score 0):

### [Create a Security Seal in Illustrator Using Guilloche Patterns](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-security-seal-in-illustrator-using-guilloche-patterns--vector-4828)

This comprehensive tutorial will help you with all your **Guilloche** pattern needs! I was just researching on my own and found this post and this link. Figured I might as well respond with what I had found in my search.